# Inserting Multiple Values into a Column (Python - Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

I already have a table generated,

I wanted to add specific username values into it. Currently, they're all listed as t1 due to

```
df.insert(0,'USERNAME', 't1' , allow_duplicates = False)
```

Table =

```
USERNAME | AGE | SEX | etc etc
t1
t1
t1
t1
t1
t1
```

The other columns have values, how do I add specific values to USERNAME?
I wanted to add specific usernames such as t4, t8, t10 etc etc.

This code keeps breaking

```
df['USERNAME'] = df.append('t2','t30','t41','t5','t6')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could insert the column with a default value (say `'t1'`) and then set the values of that column from a list or a tuple:

```
lst = ('t2','t30','t41','t5','t6')
df.insert(0,'USERNAME', 't1' , allow_duplicates = False)
maxlen = min(len(df), len(lst)
df.iloc[:maxlen, 0] = lst[:maxlen]
```

This code copes with lists and dataframes of different length. If they have the same length, it could simply be:

```
lst = ('t2','t30','t41','t5','t6')
df.insert(0,'USERNAME', 't1' , allow_duplicates = False)
df['USERNAME'] = lst
```